# My Swing application is likely not thread-safe - not sure why, though

Tags: java, multithreading, swing

Edited at the request of commenters.  I hope this is compliant.

First post!  Trying to understand why my Swing application will not advance from one panel to the next.  Here is the general flow of the code :

```
public class MainWindow {

JFrame mainFrame;
ChangeablePanel currentScreen; // abstract and extends JPanel, has getters &
setters for a Timer (swing timer), a String (nextScreen), and an Image 
(background image).  also has a close(AWTEvent e) method that simply calls 
"this.setVisible(false);"

public MainWindow() {
    mainFrame = new JFrame("New Arcana");
    mainFrame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);       
    setTitleFrame();
} // MainFrame constructor

public void changeFrame(String frameType, String frameName) {               
    switch (frameType) {
        case "Title":
            setTitleFrame();
            break;
        case "Town":
            setTownFrame(frameName);
            break;
        case "Movie":
            setMovieFrame(frameName);               
            break;
        default:
            break;
    } // switch     
} // changeFrame

private void setTitleFrame() {      
    currentScreen = new TitlePanel();
    currentScreen.addComponentListener(new ScreenChangeListener());
    ...             
    mainFrame.setContentPane(currentScreen);
    mainFrame.setSize(titleScreenLength, titleScreenHeight); // put constants here if you want
    mainFrame.setLocationRelativeTo(null);
    mainFrame.setVisible(true);
} // setTitleFrame

private void setTownFrame(String townName) {        
    currentScreen = new TownPanel(townName);
    currentScreen.addComponentListener(new ScreenChangeListener());
    ...     
    mainFrame.setContentPane(currentScreen);        
    mainFrame.setSize(townScreenLength, townScreenHeight); // put constants here if you want
    mainFrame.setVisible(true);     
} // setTownFrame

private void setMovieFrame(String movieName) {      
    currentScreen = new MoviePanel(movieName);
    currentScreen.addComponentListener(new ScreenChangeListener());
    ...
    mainFrame.setContentPane(currentScreen);
    mainFrame.setSize(titleScreenLength, titleScreenHeight); // put constants here if you want      
    mainFrame.setVisible(true);     
} // setMovieFrame

private class ScreenChangeListener implements ComponentListener {
    @Override
    public void componentHidden(ComponentEvent e) {
        gotoNextScreen(e);
    }

    public void componentMoved(ComponentEvent e) {}

    public void componentResized(ComponentEvent e) {}

    public void componentShown(ComponentEvent e) {}     
} // ScreenChangeListener

public void gotoNextScreen(ComponentEvent e) {        
    changeFrame(currentScreen.getNextScreen(), null);   
}
} // MainWindow

public class Start {
...
public static void main(String[] args) {
    initialize();   

    SwingUtilities.invokeLater(new Runnable() {
        public void run() {
            new MainWindow();
        }
    });   
} // main
...
} // Start

public class TitlePanel extends ChangeablePanel implements ActionListener {

JButton newGame, continueGame;

public TitlePanel() {       
    setFocusable(true);     
    ...

    newGame = new JButton("New Game");
    continueGame = new JButton("Continue");     

    newGame.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {
        public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
            setNextScreen("Movie");
            close(e);               
        }       
    });

    add(newGame);
    add(continueGame);

    createTimer(10, this);
    getTimer().start();
} // TitlePanel constructor

@Override
public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
    repaint();      
}

public void paintComponent(Graphics g) {
    super.paintComponent(g);
    Graphics2D g2d = (Graphics2D) g;        
    drawTitleScreen(g2d);       
} // paintComponent

private void drawTitleScreen(Graphics2D g2d) {
    g2d.drawImage(getBGImage(), 0, 0, null);
    newGame.setLocation(170, 550);
    continueGame.setLocation(605, 550);
} // drawTitleScreen
} // TitlePanel

public class MoviePanel extends ChangeablePanel implements ActionListener { 

public MoviePanel(String movieName) {       
    setFocusable(true); 

    addKeyListener(new AnyKeyActionListener());
    ...
    createTimer(10, this);
    getTimer().start();
} // TitlePanel constructor

@Override
public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
    repaint();
}

public void paint(Graphics g) {
    super.paint(g);
    Graphics2D g2d = (Graphics2D) g;        
    drawMovie(g2d);     
} // paintComponent 

private void drawMovie(Graphics2D g2d) {
    g2d.drawImage(getBGImage(), 0, 0, null);        
} // drawTitleScreen    

private class AnyKeyActionListener extends KeyAdapter {     
    public void keyTyped(KeyEvent e) {
        setNextScreen("Town");
        close(e);
    } // keyPressed     
} // listener to check for keystrokes   
} // MoviePanel
```

The MainFrame is to be populated with more frames as the application advances based on user-input (currently, only MoviePanel and TownPanel are coded), and their code is fairly analogous to this one -- I pasted MoviePanel as well.

Execution breaks down after the KeyAdapter-based listener above.  However, when I run my application in Debug mode in Eclipse with breakpoints, this indeed does what it's supposed to do and advances from the MoviePanel to the TownPanel.  It is because of this that I suspect threading is the culprit here.  Note that I did try many different combinations of the SwingUtilities.invokeLater() technique on the code-blocks above, but it didn't change anything.  Any help would be appreciated; thanks!

Comment: where is the changeFrame() method?

Comment: 1) Don't extend frame or panel 2) Start the GUI on the EDT. 3) Consider [key bindings](http://stackoverflow.com/tags/key-bindings/info) for Swing. 4) For better help sooner, post an [SSCCE](http://sscce.org/).

Comment: Look at your `setTitleFrame()` method, it is not called on the `EDT` hence this is not a thread safe method. In `Swing`. Calls like `pack()/setVisible(true/false) must be inside the `EDT - Event Dispatcher Thread`

Comment: Billy M - SSCCE does not mean "post less code".  What it actually means is **reduce** your problem to a **small but complete working program** by getting rid of the extraneous stuff.  What you've posted is not an SSCCE because 1) it isn't runnable code, 2) has included a bunch of extraneous stuff and 3) has left out important stuff.

Comment: Thank you all for the feedback, since this is my first stackoverflow post I'll take any help on the standards I can get.  @Stephen C, It is hard to tell what is extraneous and what is not, because my issue is thread-safety -- ANYTHING could be important.  In any case, I pasted a lot more of my code now.  Thanks.

Comment: @BillyM. Extraneous means that you can remove it from the SSCCE without stopping the SSCCE from demonstrating the bug / whatever. Q: How do you know what you can remove?  A: Just try it.

Comment: Thanks all, it appears the issue all along was that my panel was not receiving focus, so it could not respond to key strokes, and threading may not have been an issue at all.  This was solved by setting "mainFrame.getContentPane().requestFocus()" inside of the setMovieFrame method of MainWindow.  I also since changed to the key binding that was suggested, and it makes the code a lot tidier.  In the meantime, I learned a good chunk about swing in the meantime.  Thanks again.  I'll be back!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Do the following:

- invokeLater for creation ont the GUI Event Dispatch Thread
- No repaint() during construction
- setVisible last

Especially on event listeners again use invokeLater, to let buttons and such be responsive, and have then actions being taken with response too.

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    ...
    SwingUtilities.invokeLater() {
        @Override()
        new Runnable() {
            new MainFrame().setVisible(true);
        }
    };        
}
```

---

***Code review***

In `TitlePanel.TitlePanel` better use an absolute layout (that means null), instead of using `setLocation` in the painting code.

```
    setLayout(null);
    newGame = new JButton("New Game");
    continueGame = new JButton("Continue");
    newGame.setBounds(170, 550, 120, 24);
    continueGame.setBounds(605, 550, 120, 24);
```

In `ChangeablePanel.close` ensure also `timer.stop()`.

In `MainWindow` use `invokeLater`:

```
public void gotoNextScreen(ComponentEvent e) {
    SwingUtilities.invokeLater(new Runnable() {
        @Override
        public void run() {
            changeFrame(currentScreen.getNextScreen(), null);
        }
    });   
}
```

In `MoviePanel` **I cannot see that `addKeyListener` could function**; maybe the left-out code? Or is this maybe the error you saw?
Furthermore I find a simple `repaint()` dubious; would have expected something like:

```
public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
    invalidate();
    repaint(10L);
}
```

Comment: Thanks Joop, didn't work unfortunately, same issue.  Updated the main problem with latest code.

Comment: Thanks again Joop, see the above solution for resolution.  I appreciate all this help.